# Java - Converting from unicode to a string?

Tags: java, string, unicode, character

I can easily create a unicode character and print it with the following lines of code

```
String uniChar = Character.toString((char)0000);
System.out.println(uniChar);
```

However, now I want to retrieve the number above, add 3, and print out the new unicode character that the numbers 0003 corresponds to. Is there a way for me to retrieve the ACTUAL string of unichar? As in "\u0000"? That way I could substring just the "0000", convert it to an int, add 3, and reverse the entire process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`String#codePointAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePointAt-int-):

> Returns the character (Unicode code point) at the specified index. The index refers to char values (Unicode code units) and ranges from 0 to length()- 1.
>
> If the char value specified at the given index is in the high-surrogate range, the following index is less than the length of this String, and the char value at the following index is in the low-surrogate range, then the supplementary code point corresponding to this surrogate pair is returned. Otherwise, the char value at the given index is returned.

For instance ([live copy](https://ideone.com/Op2yBT)):

```
// String containing smiling face with smiling eyes emoji
String str = "";
// Get the code point
int cp = str.codePointAt(0);
// Show it
System.out.println(str + ", code point = U+" + toHex(cp));
// Increase it
++cp;
// Get the updated string (from an array of code points)
String updated = new String(new int[] { cp }, 0, 1);
// Show it
System.out.println(updated + ", code point = U+" + toHex(cp));
```

(`toHex` is just `return Integer.toString(n, 16).toUpperCase();`)

That outputs:

```
, code point = U+1F60A

, code point = U+1F60B
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: @user07 - No, the *answer* (`String.codePointAt`) works just fine with code points that require two code units (pedantically, in Java there are no "1 byte" code points in strings -- Java strings use UTF-16 [essentially]). The *example* in the answer used a one-code-unit code point, but that was just an example. I've added an example with a two code-unit code point.

Comment: @user07 - Ah! I see what you mean. I've updated to show creating a string from an array of code points after accessing the code point. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This code will work in both cases, for codepoints from Unicode BMP and from Unicode supplemental panes which uses 4 bytes in UTF-8 to encode a character. 4 byte code point requires 2 Java char entities to be stored, so in this case string.length() = 2.

```
// array will contain one or two characters
char[] chars = Character.toChars(codePoint);

// string.length will be 1 or 2
String str = new String(chars);
```

Comment: This doesn't show the basic aspect of the question: How to access the code point of the character in the string.

Comment: It answers the title of the question. I came to this page only because of the title and I did not find the answer that helped me. So here you are.

Comment: title != question. I respectfully suggest either answering the actual question, or deleting the answer. Answers that don't answer the question aren't useful, and so they accumulate downvotes over time.

Answer (score 1):

Unicode is a numbering of "characters" - **code points** - upto a 3-byte int range.

The UTF-16 encoding uses a sequance of byte pairs, and a java **char** is such a byte pair. The `(int)` cast of a char is imperfect and covers only a part of the Unicode. The correct way to convert a code point to possibly more than one char:

```
int codePoint = 0x263B;
char[] chars = Character.chars(codePoint);
```

To work with Unicode code points, one can do:

```
int[] codePoints = {0x2639, 0x263a, 0x263b};
String s = new String(codePoints, 0, codePoints.length);
codePoints[0} += 2;
```

You code use an int array of 1 code point.

In java 8 one can get an IntStream of code points:

```
s.codePoints().forEach(cp -> {
    System.out.printf("U+%X = %s%n", cp, Character.getName(cp));
};
```